# Azure release add artifact

Tags: azure-devops

Within Azure Devops I have a build pipeline which builds and publishes artifacts and a release pipeline which downloads those artifacts, defines some infrastructure configuration, and batch uploads the artifacts to a web container.

After the configuration definition I want to add a task to fetch the clientId of an AD registered app,  dumps it into a json file and copies the file in the same folder as the build artifacts. The json has to be uploaded to the web container to provide runtime configuration for a spa app.

What I have tried:

- generate a json in a release task and copy it into said folder
- commit an empty json in the code, have it published as build artifact and update its content in a release task
- use the file transform task which only seem to allow updating a key / value, not generating a new one

The contents of the folder which gets uploaded seem to be locked. 
Is that correct ? What can I do to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Releases don't publish artifacts. Releases **consume** published artifacts. A release can be run multiple times for the same build. A release can have multiple environments. What you want to do would fall apart immediately in any of those scenarios.

What you *should* do is write a custom BASH or Powershell script (depending on your preferences and OS) that does exactly what you describe:

- Generate an appropriate JSON file
- Upload the JSON file to the "web container"

You haven't provided any details about what a "web container" is or what your deployment environment is (i.e. AWS, Azure, containers running in Kubernetes), so that's the most thorough answer that can be provided.

Comment: Thanks your answer was very helpful, I ended up doing what you suggested.

Comment: I find it quite difficult to understand why artifacts cannot be produced in the release pipeline. I am deploying to a $web container of a static website of an Azure storage account. App registration is done in the release and I want to create a json file containing the app clientId and tenantId in the release and upload it to the web container alongside the other assets. 

When the ui loads it fetches this configuration for single sign on authentication.

Comment: Essentially I am building once and fetching environment config at runtime. If you believe this approach is wrong please feel free to let me know.